# Any tool/code/link/book on migration of visualforce pages and apex classes to lightning components - help needed

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

If anyone has done/knows regarding migration from classic code to Lightning component, requesting you to suggest the way.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your Visualforce code [Lightning Ready](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Lightning_Ready) relatively easily as an intermediate step.

But changing to using Lightning Components is a re-write. Also you will first have to learn about the technology - see e.g. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails and click on the "Lightning" link - which will take some time.

I haven't seen any tools aimed at such a migration.